# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'videos_set'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I am trying to get all the videos related to a curriculum, I've tried `curriculum.videos.all` but it return this error that says `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'videos'`, i also tried using `curriculum.videos_set.all` then it shows the same error but this time with a `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'videos_set'`. what can be the issue with this problem?

models.py

```
class Course(models.Model):
    course_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    course_thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path, blank=True)

class Curriculum(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course , null = False , on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="curriculum")
    title  = models.CharField(max_length = 100 , null = False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.course.course_title} - {self.title}'

class Video(models.Model):
    title  = models.CharField(max_length = 100 , null = False)
    curriculum = models.ForeignKey(Curriculum , null = False , on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="videos")
    serial_number = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    video_id = models.CharField(max_length = 100 , null = False)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Now this is the view that i have written for it
View.py

```
def course_details(request, course_slug):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user = request.user
        course = Course.objects.get(slug=course_slug)
        course.views = course.views + 1

        curriculum = Curriculum.objects.filter(course=course)
        serial_number = request.GET.get('lecture')
        # videos = curriculum.videos.all().order_by("serial_number")
        # video_count = curriculum.videos.all().order_by("serial_number").count()
        videos = Video.objects.filter(curriculum=curriculum).order_by("serial_number")
        
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=course.course_creator)
        user_rating = CreatorRating.objects.filter(profile=profile).aggregate(Avg('rating'))['rating__avg']

        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
        follow_status = Follow.objects.filter(following=course.course_creator, follower=request.user).exists()
        followers_count = Follow.objects.filter(following=course.course_creator).count()
        liked = CourseLikes.objects.filter(user=user, course=course).count()

        post_tags_ids = course.tags.values_list('id', flat=True)
        similar_posts = Course.objects.filter(tags__in=post_tags_ids).exclude(id=course.id)
        similar_posts = similar_posts.annotate(same_tags=Count('tags')).order_by('-same_tags','-date_created')
        
        rating_average = CourseRating.objects.filter(course=course).aggregate(Avg('rating'))['rating__avg']
        reviews = CourseRating.objects.filter(active=True, course=course).order_by("-date")
        reviews_count = CourseRating.objects.filter(active=True, course=course).count()
        rating_count = CourseRating.objects.filter(course=course, rating__in=["3.0", "4.0", "5.0"]).count()
        discussions = CourseDiscussion.objects.filter(active=True, course=course).order_by('-date')
        enrolled_student_count = UserCourse.objects.filter(course=course).count()
        user_courses = Course.objects.filter(course_creator=course.course_creator).count()
        students_enrolled_for_a_creator = UserCourse.objects.filter(course__course_creator=course.course_creator).count()
        all_star = CourseRating.objects.filter(course__course_creator=course.course_creator).count()
        # lectures = Video.objects.filter(curriculum=curriculum).count()
        recent_courses = Course.objects.filter(course_publish_status="published").order_by("?")[:3]

        is_liked = False
        if course.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            is_liked = True
        is_saved = False
        if profile.favourite_course.filter(slug=course_slug).exists():
            is_saved = True
        # Course Rating Feature
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = CourseRatingForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                rating_form = form.save(commit=False)
                rating_form.user = request.user
                rating_form.course = course
                rating_form.save()
                messages.success(request, f'You review was sent successfully!')
                return redirect("course:course-detail", course.slug)
        else:
            form = CourseRatingForm
        
        # Course Discusion Feature
        if request.method == "POST":
            discform = CourseDiscussionForm(request.POST)
            if discform.is_valid():
                disc_form = discform.save(commit=False)
                disc_form.user = request.user
                disc_form.course = course
                disc_form.save()
                messages.success(request, f'Posted!')
                return redirect("course:course-detail", course.slug)
        else:
            discform = CourseDiscussionForm

        #For the color of the favorite button
        if profile.favourite_course.filter(slug=course_slug).exists():
            favorited = True
        else:
            favorited = False
        
        if liked == True:
            liked = True
        else:
            liked = False

        if serial_number is None:
            serial_number = 1

        
        # if Video.objects.all().exists
        # video, created = Video.objects.get_or_create(serial_number=serial_number, curriculum=curriculum)
        video, created = Video.objects.get_or_create(serial_number=serial_number, curriculum=curriculum)
        # video_count = Video.objects.get(serial_number=serial_number, course=course)
        video.save()
        
        if(video.is_preview is False):

            if request.user.is_authenticated is False:
                return redirect("course:sign-in")
            else:
                user = request.user
                try:
                    user_course = UserCourse.objects.get(user=user, course=course)
                except:
                    return redirect("course:check-out", slug=course.slug)

        # if request.user.is_authenticated:
        #   student = request.user.student
        #   order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(student=student, completed=False)
        #   items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        #   cartItems = order.get_cart_items

        # else:
        #   items = []

        course.save()

        context = {
            'enrolled_student_count':enrolled_student_count,
            'user_courses':user_courses,
            "reviews" : reviews, 
            # "lectures" : lectures, 
            "reviews_count" : reviews_count, 
            "rating_count" : rating_count, 
            "followers_count" : followers_count, 
            "follow_status" : follow_status, 
            "favorited" : favorited, 
            "all_star" : all_star, 
            "liked" : liked, 
            'recent_courses': recent_courses,
            'is_liked': is_liked,
            "video" : video, 
            "form" : form, 
            'discussions': discussions,
            'discform': discform,
            # "video_count" : video_count, 
            'videos':videos,
            'course': course,
            'students_enrolled_for_a_creator': students_enrolled_for_a_creator,
            'is_saved':is_saved,
            'rating_average':rating_average,
            'user_rating':user_rating,
            'similar_posts':similar_posts,
            # 'cartItems': cartItems,
        }
        return render(request, 'course/course-detail.html', context)
    else:
        user = request.user
        course = Course.objects.get(slug=course_slug)
        course.views = course.views + 1
        serial_number = request.GET.get('lecture')
        videos = course.videos.all().order_by("serial_number")
        video_count = course.videos.all().order_by("serial_number").count()
        
        post_tags_ids = course.tags.values_list('id', flat=True)
        similar_posts = Course.objects.filter(tags__in=post_tags_ids).exclude(id=course.id)
        similar_posts = similar_posts.annotate(same_tags=Count('tags')).order_by('-same_tags','-date_created')
        

        rating_average = CourseRating.objects.filter(course=course).aggregate(Avg('rating'))['rating__avg']
        reviews = CourseRating.objects.filter(active=True, course=course).order_by("-date")
        reviews_count = CourseRating.objects.filter(active=True, course=course).count()
        rating_count = CourseRating.objects.filter(course=course, rating__in=["3.0", "4.0", "5.0"]).count()
        discussions = CourseDiscussion.objects.filter(active=True, course=course).order_by('-date')
        enrolled_student_count = UserCourse.objects.filter(course=course).count()
        user_courses = Course.objects.filter(course_creator=course.course_creator).count()
        students_enrolled_for_a_creator = UserCourse.objects.filter(course__course_creator=course.course_creator).count()
        all_star = CourseRating.objects.filter(course__course_creator=course.course_creator).count()
        lectures = Video.objects.filter(course=course).count()
        recent_courses = Course.objects.filter(course_publish_status="published").order_by("?")[:3]

        is_liked = False
        if course.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            is_liked = True
        is_saved = False


        if serial_number is None:
            serial_number = 1

        
        # if Video.objects.all().exists
        video, created = Video.objects.get_or_create(serial_number=serial_number, course=course)
        video_count = Video.objects.get(serial_number=serial_number, course=course)
        video.save()
        
        if(video.is_preview is False):

            if request.user.is_authenticated is False:
                return redirect("course:sign-in")
            else:
                user = request.user
                try:
                    user_course = UserCourse.objects.get(user=user, course=course)
                except:
                    return redirect("course:check-out", slug=course.slug)



        course.save()

        context = {
            'enrolled_student_count':enrolled_student_count,
            'user_courses':user_courses,
            "reviews" : reviews, 
            "lectures" : lectures, 
            "reviews_count" : reviews_count, 
            "rating_count" : rating_count, 
            'similar_posts':similar_posts,
            "all_star" : all_star, 
            'recent_courses': recent_courses,
            "video" : video, 
            'discussions': discussions,
            "video_count" : video_count, 
            'videos':videos,
            'course': course,
            'students_enrolled_for_a_creator': students_enrolled_for_a_creator,
            'is_saved':is_saved,
            'rating_average':rating_average,
        }
        return render(request, 'course/course-detail.html', context)
```

Comment: Do you want to get all videos related to curriculum or simply want all videos?

Comment: @SunderamDubey yes, all the videos related to a curriculum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should query like this using [`filter()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#filter) if you want to get all videos related to curriculum:

```
# @login_required
def course_details(request, course_slug):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user = request.user
        course = Course.objects.get(slug=course_slug)

        curriculum = Curriculum.objects.filter(course=course)
        serial_number = request.GET.get('lecture')
        
        videos = Video.objects.filter(curriculum=curriculum).order_by('serial_number')
        
        ...
```

> `Note:` It is generally better to use [`get_object_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) instead of [`get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#get), it automatically handles http 404 error.

Use as:

```
 course = get_object_or_404(Course,slug=course_slug)
```

Comment: the other error is resolved now i am getting this error `The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.` and that is because i am trying to `get`.  `video, created = Video.objects.get_or_create(serial_number=serial_number, curriculum=curriculum)`. i think the error is coming becuase of this `  curriculum = Curriculum.objects.filter(course=course)`. please how do i fix this?

Comment: @DestinyFranks Can you share entire view?

Comment: @DestinyFranks One mistake I could see is this `form = CourseRatingForm` in else condition, but it should be `form = CourseRatingForm()`.

Comment: okay, I fixed that, so is there any fix for this error `The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `Video` manager and filter by the curriculum instance.

Try it like this:

```
# @login_required
def course_details(request, course_slug):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user = request.user
        course = Course.objects.get(slug=course_slug)

        curriculum = Curriculum.objects.filter(course=course)
        serial_number = request.GET.get('lecture')
        videos = Video.objects.filter(curriculum=curriculum).order_by('serial_number')
        ...
```

More info in the [official docu](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/managers/)